# isset($var) vs. @$var

Tags: php, error-handling

Is this an okay practice or an acceptable way to use PHP's error suppressing?

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id']) && $_REQUEST['id'] == 6) {
  echo 'hi';
}

if (@$_REQUEST['id'] == 6) {
  echo 'hi';
}
```

EDIT:
I thought so too. The code (and idea) is from friend.
Thanks for proving me right. :)

Comment: EDIT: Added closing parenthesis to `isset()` call.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not a really good practice to use error suppressing. It's even not a good practice to use $_REQUEST at all. Just use isset() or !empty() or whatever, don't be lazy.

And one more thing, it is a "good practice" to close parenthesis when using isset() :)

Comment: You can also use `array_key_exists` to check if variable send by browser

Comment: yeah, that's why I added "or whatever" :)

Comment: I've upvoted this, but for completeness you could add some explanation for the OP about the reasons.

Answer (score 17):

Suppressing the errors using @ only suppresses the display of the error, not the creation. So you get a small performance hit from the error if you don't check isset() first.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not really an acceptable practice in my opinion. Apart from the fact that it looks sloppy, custom error handlers are still triggered even when using error suppression.

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) offers more reasons to avoid its use altogether:

> Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to why.

Answer (score 2):

i always use isset() as it's more specific. Also, i'd use a more specific superglobal variable, so use either $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION. Being clear with your code avoids headaches later on :)

This is how i run my checks:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] == '6')
{
     // do stuff
}
```

This is pretty thorough checking, since it checks for an existance of a post, then whether my variable is part of the post, and finally if those two pass, it checks to see if my variable is equal to 6.

Comment: The initial boolean check for `$_POST` is unnecessary. Also, using `isset` is preferred to using `array_key_exists`, it's many times faster. The only advantage is if you want to check if 'id' exists but is null.

Comment: @ryeguy thanks for the advice! :) thinking about it now yeah its a bit silly since array_key_exists iterates over the array doesn't it?

Comment: I initially thought this too, but it isn't true. If you benchmark `array_key_exists` you'll realize it's `O(1)`, just like `isset`. I think `isset` is quicker simply because it's a language construct, so there is no function call overhead like there is to `array_key_exists`.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from being not a good practice, since `@` can chew on really important errors down the call stack, performance penalty is minuscule.

Let's verify this with a benchmark.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

$limit = 10000;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    echo !isset($_GET['aaa']) ? '' : $_GET['aaa'];
}
$total = 1000000 * (microtime(true) - $start)/$limit;
echo "With isset: $total μs\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    echo @$_GET['aaa'];
}
$total = 1000000 * (microtime(true) - $start)/$limit;
echo "With @: $total μs\n";
```

On my not-so-recent computer it outputs:

```
With isset: 0.295 μs
With @: 0.657 μs
```

μs is a millionth of a second. Both methods take close to half of a millionth of a second.

One could say, but what if I do this for hundreds or thousands times, will there will be any difference? If you have to do `!isset()` a million of times, then your program already spent about 0.3 second doing this! Which means that you shouldn't have been doing that in the first place.

Nevertheless, `@` is a bad practice for anything more complex than a simple array, hence *do not use it* even if you know that performance difference is insignificant.