# For a form check what is recommended isset() or '@'

Tags: php

What is preferred `isset($_POST['start_time'])` or `@$_POST['start_time']`

Comment: I would use isset.  Manually suppressing errors is never a good idea.

Comment: dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600312/issetvar-vs-var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Neither.**

`isset` is "this exists *and has a value*", and that's not *always* what you want.

Consider [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead:

```
if(array_key_exists('foo', $_POST)) {
    // code in here will operate if the key exists
    // and can do whatever it needs with the value.
}
```

Too annoying?  Also consider [`filter_input`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), with the appropriate `INPUT_POST` or `INPUT_GET` flag.  Shorter, neater, built-in validation, *and* no notices about missing keys.

```
$foo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Comment: interesting... what would you say about `$foo=isset($_POST['foo'])?(int)$_POST['foo']:0;`? it has fewer characters and no _obnoxious_ constants.

Comment: Agreed on the obnoxious constants factor.  My own code actually has a quick wrapper to reduce the noise slightly.  With regard to `isset`, my beef with it has to do with detecting "does it have a value" instead of "is it *missing*".  `isset` returns `false` for an array key that exists but is null.  Sometimes, you need to know that the `null` was present.  Your example code is perfectly fine as long as `0` is an acceptable value when `$_POST['foo']` is *either* missing *or* `null`.

Comment: Thanks, i should have figured that out from your initial post. I'm curious though, do you know of a situation where a browser would submit a POST or GET var actually set to `null` and not a string version `'null'` or `''` (empty string)?

Comment: @Shad, that should generally not happen with POST or GET variables, though it can easily happen with user-generated arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Suppressing errors is not at all a good idea. I prefer using `isset()`