# PHP suppressing vs. 'if' to avoid notices

Tags: php, session, suppress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [isset($var) vs. @$var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600312/issetvar-vs-var)

If there is a likelihood that `$_SESSION` won't be set on page load, what would be considered best practice in cases like the below? Is it considered OK to suppress notices like `Undefined index`, which would be the result of the second example if there was no `@` in front of it. How far is it worth going to have "error free" code considering processor usage (though the difference must be minimal in the cases below).

```
if( isset($_SESSION['sessionvar']) ){ $seen = $_SESSION['sessionvar']; }
```

vs.

```
@$sessionid = $_SESSION['sessionvar'];
```

Comment: They both have good and bad but depends on its use good question to ask but not for SO as it's argumentative

Comment: Possible duplicate "[isset($var) vs. @$var](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2600312/1456376)".

Comment: personal preference, move on.

Comment: I suppose its not argumentative considering the 'processor usage' part.

Comment: both are supported buy the core there both were developed into it so there both proper usage of the core and that comment has just sparked a debate point proven

Comment: if your choice of either makes *any* difference to performance something else is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @Dagon Sorry there is a reason i did not say something like that, 
ok lets do this comaird with none,
none  - Less code less memory, notice is fired more memory,
@$..  - 1 more so 2 bytes more memory, notice is fired more memory,
isset - more code more memory, notice is not fired but more code to execute, so from all of that the only way to truly know is to build some test into php core just to test that to see if the difference could be spoted unless there is a php dev that has done that on here that can answer it's not much help