# Turn off or handle errors within a production environment?

Tags: php

After having an argument with my team because we all have different views on this sort of situation.. When is it actually acceptable to turn off PHP error messages, or to suppress some functions which are throwing warnings, notices for whatever reason..

I understand everyone says that you should turn off error_reporting within a production environment, but that might cause some complications which will not be picked up.. So nothing will get fixed, furthermore. PHP comes with many different methods to control error messages.. For example:

```
$Var = "Variable Is Set";

if (@$Var){ echo $Var; }
```

Over:

```
if (isset($Var)){ echo $Var; }
```

Because we have a set variable, this will sucessfully echo.. Whereas if we didn't have a set variable, this would throw a notice.. So Which one to use? The isset or error suppression?

And within a production environment, which one would be more acceptable to use?

```
error_reporting(0);
```

The above will turn off all types of PHP error reporting, giving no error messages even if something is encountered. So in some cases this could lead to broken code that stops working for an unknown reason, due to the message being destroyed

or:

```
set_error_handler("");
```

The above enables a custom error handler, which can be used to gracefully show a error to the user, and enable administration to log the detailed warning.. But then again, the error_handler to my knowledge will not be called when a fatal error is triggered?

So My overall question?

Handle errors in production environment or just turn them off in general? This boils down to best practices and preferences I guess.. But it's something that is puzzling me and my team to the point of disagreements.

Comment: The first hald of this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600312/issetvar-vs-var

Comment: IF your team likes to to turn off error reporting in production, I would show them [this picture](http://www.ostrichheadinsand.com/images/ostrich-head-in-sand.jpg) and make fun of their lameness.

Comment: @chris You have just won the internet!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, this is not a definite solution, but after several years of trial and error, I came up with the following practices, which are just my own, and work pretty well:

1 - Never use @ to suppress errors. Never use anything to blindly hide or ignore all errors. ALL errors are important, no error should be ignored.

2 - Do as RafaSashi suggested, turn on error logging and turn off display errors.

3 - Activate ALL error reporting, by using `error_reporting = 2147483647` in PHP.INI. That will make PHP very picky with anything you may do wrongly, helping you learn more and stay up to date with future language deprecations and changes.

4 - You can also create you own error logging, to log exactly what you want, the way you want. Look up the manual for `error_log()`. If you use it, you can even turn looging off, and start logging manually, that will give you full control of PHP's error logging system.

5 - I use OOP in all my PHP code, so I use exceptions everywhere, and I recommend the same for everyone. They're light-years ahead of simply error handling. Use this code to intercept all errors in your code and throw them as exceptions:

```
set_error_handler('ErrorHandler');
function ErrorHandler($Code, $Message)
{
  throw new Exception($Message, $Code);
}
```

6 - Not showing ANY errors to the user is simply non-sense. Some errors should be shown, some should be hidden, and some should be shown as a generic issue (don't tell the user exactly what the problem is).

a) **Errors that should be shown:** everything caused by the user, like invalid form input or wrong behavior. This is quite obvious, but should be mentioned.

b) **Errors that should be hidden:** hide only the errors your code can handle and correct. For example, you can do a DB connection, and if it fails, you can try again. If the second attempt succeeds, go ahead, no one should ever know the first try failed. Just log it if you want, using `error_log()`. Sometimes, variables don't exist yet, so check this with `isset()`, and initialize them if needed. No need to report this as an error too.

c) **Errors that should be shown as generic:** most errors will fall in this category. You will not show the user things like PHP memory exhausted, or that a SMTP server is offline, or that a DB connection was refused. Just learn how to wrap dangerous code with a `try`, use a catch to capture any error, and convert the message to something you can show to the user. Example:

```
try
{
  // Dangerous code ahead: we will try to connect to the database, but it 
  // can be offline.
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  // If we're here, something bad happened during connection. Let's handle it.

  // Notify staff, log error, do anything you can to get someone to quickly 
  // check the issue.
  SendMailAdmin("Database connection Error, check ASAP.");
  error_log("Database connection Error, check ASAP.");

  // And show the user some message. You don't need to tell him about any 
  // detail regarding what truly caused the error.
  die("A problem occurred in our servers. Our technical staff has been notified, 
      please try again in a few minutes.");
}

// If we're here, everything worked fine, so do your DB query and so on....
```

Instead of a `die()`, you can use what you see fit: re-throw as another exception, do a header redirect to a generic error message or whatever you want.

7 - This is more advanced, but you can do it also: create you own exception hierarchy, like this:

```
class MVXException extends Exception {}
    class ExMVXDB extends MVXException {}
      class ExMVXDBRead extends ExMVXDB { }
      class ExMVXDBWrite extends ExMVXDB { }
      class ExMVXDBNotFound extends ExMVXDB { }
```

This is a simplification of the exceptions tree I have in my self-made framework. The beauty of this is that if you do a `catch(ExMVXDB $e)`, you will catch ALL DB errors. But if you want to catch only a data writing operation, you can do a `catch(ExMVXDBWrite $e)`.

That's it. Error handling is not simple, and there's no direct answer, but there are plenty of tools and good practices to help you choose what's best for you.

Answer (score 6):

You *never* simply **turn off** error reporting entirely. You *do* turn off *error display*. Directly dumping errors to the screen is necessary during development (unless you have other methods which throw all errors in your face), in production you want the same error *reporting* but instead of it outputting visible errors, you want it to only log them. This can all be done using PHP's error reporting configuration settings.

If you want special custom error handling/logging, use a custom error handler.

As for `@`, you never write your application in a way that it produces actual errors on whose behavior you rely. You write everything in a way that does not trigger errors. You only use `@` when there's no way to avoid a possible error because you cannot write it any other way, and you *expect* an error and are *handling* it; then all you do it to suppress the inevitable error message.

Comment: but you should halt the execution instead of showing a bug I think instead of like seting empty value in an undefined variable I think. Otherwise user might think his data are correct while it is not correct and does not even know he needs to contact support.

Comment: Not entirely sure how that relates to my answer…

Answer (score 2):

1 - You can turn off display_errors and turn on log_errors

```
@ini_set('log_errors','On');

@ini_set('display_errors','Off');
```

2 - You can use the default php Error and Logging functions & constants

See: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_error.asp

3 - You can implement your own set of error and logging functions with the PHP Filesystem

See: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filesystem.asp

Comment: W3Schools is a terrible resource. I suggest using the official PHP docs instead.

Comment: As harsh as this sounds.. This is slightly informative to non experienced users.. Though i'm aware of the methods you have given. -1 for using W3School as it's untrust worthy