# Symfony2 array to string conversion error handling in production

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services

Amateur here.

Using Symfony 2.6.13.

Production environment: AWS Linux, Elastic Beanstalk.
Development environment: WAMP.

I have an error which is confusing me as it only causes me an issue in development. Here is an extract from the error log on production:

```
[Wed Feb 22 10:40:16.484644 2017] [:error] [pid 12453] [client 172.31.46.85:18619] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/app/current/app/cache/prod/twig/db/dbafcb45562bb5839ccefc3c501bc398a96f8c34fd19c0f11d60122efe04cb15.php on line 220, referer: https://xxx-xxx.xxx.com/contact/986513/risk/1
```

I get this error in both the production and development environment. In production the error seems to be ignored and the page loads. In development the error is not ignored and the page errors saying the following:

```
CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion")
```

Why would this error be ignore in production but not in development?

Comment: Probably because the production does not have error reporting configured in php.ini as the development does. Find the variable in template that it's trying to display as it was a string. I mean did you try to fix the cause?

Comment: ive mirrored the setting on development, in WAMP. I've turned off error reporting on wamp and AWS (production).

Comment: You might have used {{variable}} in twig, and variable will be of type array, this is one reason you get above exception.

Comment: The cache of twig templates is automatically refreshed in `dev`, can you `cache:clear -env=prod`

Comment: @user1077250 Turning off error reporting in dev env is not a solution. Besides, the error does not seem like a tough one. Go over the variables in template, put each one in dump() function, and see which one is the unexpected array. Like so: `{{ dump(someVar) }}` .

Comment: I have found the error, it was caused by some bad data. However, I still have the issue that in production the error does not cause the page to not load and in development this error caused the page not to load. Is that as @Duro Mandinic said? Could it be my development server config? I've turned off error reporting on my development server and it still errors.

Comment: "Directly dumping errors to the screen is necessary during development (unless you have other methods which throw all errors in your face), in production you want the same error reporting but instead of it outputting visible errors, you want it to only log them." http://stackoverflow.com/a/17135464/2484968

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was that I wasn't aware of the difference between the development and production environment. I was expecting the error I received in development also to cause the same type of error in production and stop the page loading.

I need to understand the differences between the two environments in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `error_reporting` to `'0'` immediately before rendering, then setting it back to its original value afterwards.

This prevents 'Array to string conversion' errors being thrown which otherwise stop the template being rendered at all.

Instead, you'll see it gets outputted as `Array` in the rendered text.

We can easily achieve this using `ini_set()`.

Example below.

---

My twig helper class's render method looks like this, and works great:

```php
    public function render(string $name, array $params): string
    {
        $this->setIniSettings();

        try {
            $result = $this->twig->render($name, $params);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $this->restoreIniSettings();
            throw $e;
        }

        $this->restoreIniSettings();
        return $result;
    }
```

I have a config file which defines the ini settings for rendering twig templates setup like so:

```php
return [
    'ini_settings' => [
        'error_reporting' => '0'
    ],
];
```

In `setIniSettings()` i just loop over an array of settings i have defined in my config file like so:

```php
    protected function setIniSettings()
    {
        $this->oldIniSettings = [];

        foreach (config('twig.ini_settings', []) as $setting => $value) {
            $this->oldIniSettings[$setting] = ini_set($setting, $value);
        }
    }
```

And then `restoreIniSettings()` looks like this:

```php
    protected function restoreIniSettings()
    {
        foreach ($this->oldIniSettings as $setting => $value) {
            ini_set($setting, $value);
        }
    }
```